# How to configue a shutdownHook to the Runtime in Spring

Tags: spring

I am Working on bean life cycle and i am using the callback interfaces:  'InitializingBean' and 'DisposableBean' for implementing lifecycle methods, apart from this in my main class i tried to add a shutdownHook to the 
Runtime object so that i do not need to call the

`((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) factory).destroySingletons();`

manually. that's where i created a class ShutdownHook as

```
    public class ShutDownHook implements Runnable, BeanFactoryAware {

        private BeanFactory factory;

        @Override
        public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
            System.out.println("performing aware injection");
            this.factory = factory;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) factory).destroySingletons();  -----> X
        }

    }
```

and my main class is like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("com/bli/common/application-context.xml"));
    Math math = factory.getBean("math", Math.class);


    ShutDownHook shutDownHook = factory.getBean("shutdownhook", ShutDownHook.class);
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutDownHook()));

}
```

and following is my Bean on which i want to perform initialization and destruction

```
public class Math implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {


@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("destroyed....");
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("performed initialization ...");
}
```

and i have configured the required beans in spring bean configurtion file as

```
<bean id="math" class="com.bli.beans.Math">
    <constructor-arg value="10"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="y" value="20"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="shutdownhook" class="com.bli.beans.ShutDownHook"></bean>
```

After executing this program i am getting RuntimeException as

```
    performed initialization ...
    performing aware injection
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bli.beans.ShutDownHook.run(ShutDownHook.java:20)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i'e when the controll is coming to the run method of shutdownHook class the reference to the factory is getting lost .. i don't know why 
the exception is coming on line (x) which i have marked above in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace all of the above logic with single call in your main method:

```
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

Please note that you need to use instance derived from `AbstractApplicationContext` instead of `BeanFactory` but this is easy to achieve (i.e. create instance of `GenericXmlApplicationContext`).

See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--) for the method

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your main method as snipped below and your problem of NullPointerException would get resolve :)**

```
 ShutDownHook shutDownHook = factory.getBean("shutdownhook", ShutDownHook.class);
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.addShutdownHook(new Thread(shutDownHook));
```